# GGVENN: how to fix the warning message - guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

I was using the ggvenn function without any problems before, but I recently got this error messsage with the same code. Please find an example that give me the same wrning message.

```
A=c("blue", "green", 'purple', "orange")
B=c("blue", "yellow", "black", "pink")
C=c("pink", "red", "orange", "green")
D=c("green", "blue", "orange")


ListeVenn=list(A=A, B=B, C=C, D=D)

ggvenn(ListeVenn)


"Warning message:
`guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> = "none")` instead."
```

The  veen  diagramm is  made  but  without  any colours and some lines are missing

Below is the plot I am obtaining following the warning message [image]

Comment: What version of ggvenn do you have?

Comment: After checking, it seems to be ‘0.1.8’ version. Indeed it could be a version issue as I had to re install this package.

Comment: 0.1.8 is the current version. I don't get a warning and I get colour. Maybe check your ggplot2 version is current

Comment: I installed the last version of ggplot2: 3.3.5, and I still have the same issue

Comment: also here now problems. I'm using `R version 4.0.5`, `ggplot2_3.3.3 ` and `ggvenn_0.1.8`

Comment: I found this in other packages as well. In their case it hasn't been maintained since ggplot2 v.3.0.0; but if ggvenn is being maintained, you might want to let them know via an issue on github.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I have let them know via an issue on github. But if someone have an idea to bypass the warning and got the wished diagramm, please tell me!

Comment: Problem solved after reporting the issue on github. A new version of ggvenn will be upload later.